# Hierarchical order in nested dictionary: design decision

Tags: python, data-structures

This might be a lame question but here it goes:

Say I have a (Python) dictionary:

```
{'k1': {'value': 10},
 'k2': {'value': 20}}
```

The above data structure is more "inefficient" compared to the one below:

```
{'value': {'k1': 10, 'k2': 20}}
```

I understand that the latter structure takes less storage, may be compressed better, and faster to transport over network.

My question is if there is a computer science or a programming principle which encourages designing data structures like the second one than the first?

Thanks

Comment: Design your data structure the for how your application is going to use said data structure. Are you going to want to look up the values of many different `k`s? If so, use the second. Or do you care more about knowing all the information about one `k`? If so, use the first.

Comment: This doesn't seem specific to Python, is it? I mean, that data is valid JSON once you replace the single quotes with double quotes.